# How to implement synchronization with timers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I have a scenario where my C# class has two methods say `DoThis()` and `DoThat()` that are called independent of each other, in any order, by an external caller. The two methods need to be synchronized in the following way:

- After a call to `DoThis()`, wait at least `t1` seconds before proceeding with `DoThat()` execution
- After a call to `DoThat()`, wait at least `t2` seconds before proceeding with `DoThis()` execution

So essentially in pseudocode:

```
static SomeCustomTimer Ta, Tb;
static TimeSpan t1, t2;

public static void DoThis()
{
    if(Tb.IsRunning())
        Tb.WaitForExpiry();

    DoStuff();
    Ta.Start(t1);
}

public static void DoThat()
{
    if(Ta.IsRunning())
        Ta.WaitForExpiry();

    DoOtherStuff();
    Tb.Start(t2);
}
```

`DoStuff()` and `DoOtherStuff()` are **not** long-running methods and do not share resources otherwise. Typically `DoThis()` and `DoThat()` will not be called concurrently. But I still need to protect against potential deadlocks.

How can I best implement `DoThis()`, `DoThat()` in C#?

**EDIT**
My scenario right now is simple in that there aren't an arbitrary number of threads calling these functions. For purpose of simplification, there's a single caller thread calling these functions in an arbitrary sequence. So the two methods will not be called concurrently, instead the caller will call these methods one-by-one in any order. I don't have control over the caller thread's code so I want to enforce the delay between successive calls to DoThis(), DoThat().

Comment: just want to check: do you want to "interupt" the execution of the other thread for some time - now matter where in the execution it is? (so the thread gets essential no processor time at all)? I guess you could try to to that with Threads but I think that this will not provent deadlocks at all - if one thread holds a lock and you pause it what do you hope to gain?

Comment: Isn't this going to create an infinite, yet delayed, loop for every call to either `DoThis` or `DoThat`? Is that what you want?

Comment: @CarstenKönig No, I don't want to interrupt thread execution. I want to prevent concurrent execution and I also want to delay starting one thread if the other just finished within a window of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy to solve with a timed latch. A latch is synchronization mechanism that is either opened or closed. When open threads are allowed to pass through. When closed threads cannot get through. A timed latch is one that will automatically reopen or reclose after a certain amount of time has elapsed. In this case we want a "normally opened" latch so the behavior is biased towards staying open. That means the latch will reopen automatically after the timeout, but close only if `Close` is explicitly called. Multiple calls to `Close` will reset the timer.

```
static NormallyOpenTimedLatch LatchThis = new NormallyOpenTimedLatch(t2);
static NormallyOpenTimedLatch LatchThat = new NormallyOpenTimedLatch(t1);

static void DoThis()
{
  LatchThis.Wait();  // Wait for it open.

  DoThisStuff();

  LatchThat.Close();
}

static void DoThat()
{
  LatchThat.Wait(); // Wait for it open.

  DoThatStuff();

  LatchThis.Close();
}
```

And we can implement our timed latch like the following.

```
public class NormallyOpenTimedLatch
{
    private TimeSpan m_Timeout;
    private bool m_Open = true;
    private object m_LockObject = new object();
    private DateTime m_TimeOfLastClose = DateTime.MinValue;

    public NormallyOpenTimedLatch(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        m_Timeout = timeout;
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        lock (m_LockObject)
        {
            while (!m_Open)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(m_LockObject);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        lock (m_LockObject)
        {
            m_Open = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(m_LockObject);
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        lock (m_LockObject)
        {
            m_TimeOfLastClose = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (m_Open)
            {
                new Timer(OnTimerCallback, null, (long)m_Timeout.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            m_Open = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        lock (m_LockObject)
        {
            TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow - m_TimeOfLastClose;
            if (span > m_Timeout)
            {
                Open();
            }
            else
            {
                TimeSpan interval = m_Timeout - span;
                new Timer(OnTimerCallback, null, (long)interval.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm..What do you need in that case:
One Thread calls DoThis some time in succession. Another can run DoThat at least t2 seconds after LAST calling of DoThat or the first one after last calling DoThat?

I think, If your target platform is Win then It is better to use WaitableTimer (however, It is not realized in .NET but you can use It through API. You need to define those functions:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 public static extern IntPtr CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr lpTimerAttributes, bool bManualReset, string lpTimerName);

 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 public static extern bool SetWaitableTimer(IntPtr hTimer, [In] ref long pDueTime,
                         int lPeriod, IntPtr pfnCompletionRoutine,
                         IntPtr lpArgToCompletionRoutine, bool fResume);

 [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
 public static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr handle, int milliseconds);
 public static uint INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

And then using It as follow:

```
private IntPtr _timer = null;

//Before first call of DoThis or DoThat you need to create timer:
//_timer = CreateWaitableTimer (IntPtr.Zero, true, null);

public static void DoThis()
{
    //Waiting until timer signaled
    WaitForSingleObject (_timer, INFINITE);

    DoStuff();
    long dueTime = 10000 * 1000 * seconds; //dueTime is in 100 nanoseconds
    //Timer will signal once after expiration of dueTime
    SetWaitableTimer (_timer, ref dueTime, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false);
}

public static void DoThis()
{
    //Waiting until timer signaled
    WaitForSingleObject (_timer, INFINITE);

    DoOtherStuff();
    long dueTime = 10000 * 1000 * seconds; //dueTime is in 100 nanoseconds
    //Timer will signal once after expiration of dueTime
    SetWaitableTimer (_timer, ref dueTime, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false);
}
```

And after using you may destroy timer by calling CloseHandle.

Comment: You can use `AutoResetEvent` [(Desc on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) for the same purpose. No need for P/Invoke. AutoResetEvents `WaitOne(Int32)` will wait until it is signalled or when the time runs out.

Comment: @Praetor12 I didn't articulate my question with complete clarity but looks like you did get my intent. Your proposed solution sounds like it can work for me. It'll help a LOT if I can figure out a way to do this without p/invoke.

Comment: @bflat Do you need that while one thread is in DoThat another thread cant enter in DoThis and vice versa or not? Can a lot of threads to be in DoThat (or do This) simultaneously? These questions must be answered until we start to think :)

Comment: @Praetor12 
> while one thread is in DoThat another thread cant enter in DoThis and vice versa or not?
Yes, I want the functions to be entered exclusively. If DoThis() is being executed, execution of DoThat() should wait till end of DoThis() plus time t1.

> Can a lot of threads to be in DoThat (or do This) simultaneously
No. Multiple threads cannot enter either function simultaneously.

Comment: @bflat And another question: If one thread ended execution of DoThis and another thread waiting t1 time to run DoThat - what do you need in case if the first thread to call DoThis again: should It to wait until the second thread ended DoThat + t2 time or execute DoThis and to set t1 time at start position?

Comment: @Praetor12 In this case, I will just fail the second call if a thread is already waiting t1 time.

Comment: -1 for P/Invoking unmanaged WinAPI functions instead of using any number of options already in the .Net Framework (i.e. System.Timers.Timer, AutoResetEvent, Monitor, etc). See Brian Gideon's answer for a more reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm trying out a possible solution to this problem using EventWaitHandle. Looking for comments / feedback. Can this work reliably?

```
// Implementation of a manual event class with a DelayedSet method
// DelayedSet will set the event after a delay period
// TODO: Improve exception handling
public sealed class DelayedManualEvent : EventWaitHandle
{
    private SysTimer timer; // using SysTimer = System.Timers.Timer;

    public DelayedManualEvent() :
        base(true, EventResetMode.ManualReset)
    {
        timer = new SysTimer();
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Elapsed +=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimeout);
    }

    public bool DelayedSet(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            double timeout = delay.TotalMilliseconds;
            if (timeout > 0 && timer != null && Reset())
            {
                timer.Interval = timeout;
                timer.Start();
                result = true;
                Trace.TraceInformation("DelayedManualEvent.DelayedSet Event will be signaled in {0}ms",
                    delay);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("DelayedManualEvent.DelayedSet Exception {0}\n{1}", 
                e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void OnTimeout(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Trace.TraceInformation("DelayedManualEvent.OnTimeout Event signaled at time {0}", e.SignalTime);
        }
        try
        {
            if (!Set())
            {
                Trace.TraceError("DelayedManualEvent.OnTimeout Event set failed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("DelayedManualEvent.OnTimeout Exception in signaling event\n{0}]\n{1}",
                ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The way I'm planning to use this:

```
// Pseudocode
static DelayedManualEvent delayedEvent = new DelayedManualEvent();
static TimeSpan t1, t2, maxTimeout;

public static void DoThis()
{
    if(!delayedEvent.WaitOne(maxTimeout))
        return;
    DoStuff();
    delayedEvent.DelayedSet(t1);
}

public static void DoThat()
{
    if(!delayedEvent.WaitOne(maxTimeout))
        return;
    DoOtherStuff();
    delayedEvent.DelayedSet(t2);
}
```

Comment: The `DelayedSet` method is not thread-safe. Also, your main code now has a different behavior than your original question. Why are the `return` statements in `DoThis` and `DoThat`?

Comment: If you're proposing an update to your question, it's customary to edit your question to include it instead of adding it as an answer. To answer your feedback request, though, no, this won't work, in large part due to your using the same instance of DelayedManualEvent in both cases. Additionally, your implementation allows any number of threads through at a time, acting as a floodgate: Either all threads wait or all threads enter both methods at once. See Brian Gideon's answer for what you should be doing instead.

Comment: @ChrisHannon Apologies, my first question here so I wasn't aware of custom. Will remember this for next time.
About the feedback, I think I still haven't been able to articulate my question correctly - the scenario is simpler. I'll edit my question to clarify.